How to integrate User Defined Function with excel formula
The following User Defined Function is referencing previous excel sheet.
Function PrevSheet()
    Application.Volatile
    PrevSheet = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Name
End Function

The following formula is okey.
=Sheet1!A1

The following formula is NOT okey. The following formula needs to repaired.
=PrevSheet()!A1


You need to use INDIRECT for this.

=Indirect(PrevSheet() & "!A1") would likely do the trick.

I dont want to use Indirect function because it is Volatile function.

Then you'll need to write that UDF to take in a cell or a row and column as an input parameter and spit back the value of the corresponding cell in the "previous sheet".

That was in the works. I added as an answer.

You're using a Volatile UDF anyway?

Your formula would return the wrong result if the sheet where it's used was not the activesheet.   It would be safer to reference Application.Caller and use that to get the "previous" sheet.

Expansion on my comment to do this all in a UDF:
Function PrevSheetVal(PrevSheetRow As Long, PrevSheetCol As Long) As String
    Application.Volatile
    PrevSheetVal = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1).Cells(PrevSheetRow, PrevSheetCol).Value
End Function

Used like:
=PrevSheetVal(1,1)

Which will return the value in cell A1 of the "Previous sheet" as defined by the sheet with an index 1 less than the Activesheet

Here's another approach:
Function PrevSheet(Optional ref As Range = Nothing)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Application.Volatile
    'if no `ref` passed then use the cell which called this function
    If ref Is Nothing Then Set ref = Application.Caller
    'get the sheet before the sheet containing `ref`
    Set ws = ref.Parent.Previous
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then 'sheet exists
        PrevSheet = ws.Range(ref.Address).Value 'return value from `ref` on ws
    Else
        PrevSheet = "No previous sheet!"
    End If
End Function

Usage: eg.
=PrevSheet(E3) on sheet 2 would return the value from sheet 1 in E3.
=PrevSheet() in D3 on sheet 2 would return D3 from sheet 1.
Note the range passed to ref could be on a different sheet from where the UDF is used...

Unless the range whose value is being returned is included in the function parameters, you have to use Volatile...

Nicely explained here - https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-10-volatile-functions-and-function-arguments/
